# ProgressDialog not showing when calling Realm async queries

Tags: android, asynchronous, realm, progressdialog

I want to display a ProgressDialog while quiring Realm database for large data, but the dialog not showing. Kindly check the code below :

```
final ProgressDialog pd= new ProgressDialog(this);
                pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.pleaseWait));
                pd.show();
RealmResults<User> realmResults = realm.where(User.class)
                        .equalTo("is_exists", true)
                        .findAllAsync();

 RealmChangeListener callback = new RealmChangeListener() {
       @Override
      public void onChange(Object elements) {
              pd.dismiss();
       }
  };
realmResults.addChangeListener(callback);
```

I'm using api version 23 and realm version 2.0.2.

What's the problem?

Comment: it may be the context you are passing with the progress dialog, try changing it to application context.

Comment: It's inside an activity and I'm using the same context

Comment: You Need to check by changing it, most of the time Progressbar is not shown because of the context only.

Comment: I tried to use the application context but with no luck

Comment: You need to hold a reference to the RealmResults, if it gets GC'ed before the query is done, the callback will not be called.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I tried to define it as  a field and the callback is called without problems, but still the dialog not displayed.

Comment: Can it be that your dialog is dismissed very shortly after it has been shown?